# How to regroup two query to have only one common result?

Tags: t-sql

I have two queries with two opposite filters in the WHERE clause. I want to group both of them to have results in the same line : Job, Paid Employee, Unpaid Employee

I'va tried the UNION command, and I'v tried to make sub-queries but I can't achieve it

These are the two queries that I have made :

```
SELECT Count(P.pre_nom_structure) AS PaidEmployee, M.met_nom AS Job
FROM t_prestataire P
INNER JOIN r_prestataire_metier R1 ON R1.prm_pre_id = P.pre_id
INNER JOIN t_metier M ON M.met_id = R1.prm_met_id
WHERE P.pre_payant = 1
GROUP BY M.met_nom


SELECT Count(P.pre_nom_structure) AS UnpaidEmployee, M.met_nom AS Job
FROM t_prestataire P
INNER JOIN r_prestataire_metier R1 ON R1.prm_pre_id = P.pre_id
INNER JOIN t_metier M ON M.met_id = R1.prm_met_id
WHERE (P.pre_payant = 0 OR P.pre_payant IS NULL) 
GROUP BY M.met_nom
```

I wanted to have on set of results with 3 columns like this :  JOb | Paid | Unpaid

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single query with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(P.pre_payant, 0) = 0 THEN 1 END) AS PaidEmployee,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN P.pre_payant = 1 THEN 1 END) AS UnpaidEmployee,
    M.met_nom AS Job
FROM t_prestataire P
INNER JOIN r_prestataire_metier R1
    ON R1.prm_pre_id = P.pre_id
INNER JOIN t_metier M
    ON M.met_id = R1.prm_met_id
GROUP BY
    M.met_nom;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice solution ! It's very elegant, I love it :)

Comment: @ordiminnie Show some love, and get some back; that's what this site is all about.